# mod_rewrite redirect http to https on different port and remove port of url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

I can't find a solution with mod_rewrite.

On the server port 80 is listening with 7080 and port 443 with 7081.
I was able to redirect requests arriving on port 7080 to port 7081:

```
<VirtualHost ip_server:7080>
    ServerName www.example.com
       
    RewriteEngine on        
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:7081%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This works if using http://www.example.com

`http://www.example.com ---- TO ----> https://www.example.com:7081/app/Login.do`

but if digit https://www.example.com without port can't not redirect with port es. https://www.example.com:7081

```
<VirtualHost ip_server:7081>
        ServerName www.example.com

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*):7081$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:7081%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*):7081$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L,PT]

        SSLEngine on
        ...         

        <IfModule mod_jk.c>
                JkMount /app/* example
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Actually I would also like to delete the port from the URL but if I don't enter the port 7081 the certificate is not detected.
The final result I would like it to be https://www.example.com/app/Login.do

Comment: "On the server port 80 is listening with 7080 and port 443 with 7081." - That doesn't make sense. What I suspect you mean is that HTTP is served on port 7080 and HTTPS is on port 7081? "This works if using http://www.example.com" - Not with what you've posted it won't. If you request `http://www.example.com` in the browser then the _browser_ will default to port 80. You would need to include the port number, ie. `http://www.example.com:7080/` for that to "work".

Comment: "I would also like to delete the port from the URL" - then why not use the default ports (80 and 443)? To remove the port from the visible URL then you need a service running (somewhere) that accepts requests to these default ports.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite! "HTTP is served on port 7080 and HTTPS is on port 7081?" yes!... because installed nginx and is listening on ports 80 and 443. Indeed stopping nginx and changing the ports in apache to the default ones and it works. I can't change the ports in nginx, most likely there is some other configuration in plesk that I can't locate.

Comment: "I can't change the ports in nginx" - Well, you can't have two services listening on the same ports. Maybe it is the intention that Nginx acts a reverse proxy in front of Apache? (Nginx then forwards requests from port 80 (Nginx) to 7080 (Apache) etc.) Otherwise, you would need to configure Nginx to manage your sites instead. Incidentally, the mod_rewrite directives in your `<VirtualHost ip_server:7081>` container don't appear to be necessary?

Comment: Nginx acts as a proxy on Apache listening on ports 7080 and 7081. I would have liked to leave the port configurations as they are from the factory and act on Apache to configure the vhosts using mod_rewrite but seeing the difficulties I permanently disabled nginx and configured Apache on default ports 80 and 443. For moment that's ok. Thanks!